# Query Database Vs Query Datatable

Tags: database, performance, dataset

I have a situation where i want to return  a count of members in a database by category i have 6 categories in all and approx 15,000 members.

Therefore is it better to query the database 6 separate times using something like "select count(*)" or is it better to return all records, returning only the category column, and then query the data resulting table for each of the 6 categories to get a count.

The first method limits the db queries to one, but returns more data which has to be processed further,

The second method queries the db six times but provides the result via less data and no further processing.

I guess what i'm asking in the database engine quicker or is .net? I'm using sqlserver 2008 with .net4

Is there any best practice or reasons people know of why i should use one method over the other?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I understand you just only need Catetory and Count. So you can do just one time query as follow.

```
SELECT CATEGORY, COUNT(CATEGRORY) TOTAL_COUNT
FROM TABLE
GROUP BY CATEGORY
```

Comment: Sorry i used the above as a simplified example of what i'm trying to do. My real question is, is it quicker to return one dataset and query it to return six different results or quicker to run 6 separate database calls?

Comment: Cheers mate ill run with a variation of this

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't seem to be a good idea to quer the DB 6 times, while you have a group by. Not to mention if you need to join the category to a category table. Besides it has the drawback that you'll have to either hardcode the categories or query the tables JUST to get the categories (if there is no separate lookup category table). If you query the database to get the 6 categories dinamically... how would you do it? With a select distinct? With a group by?

In any case just to get the categories present in all rows it'll be a heavy query. So, if you're going to perform a heavy query, at least do it in the simplest way:

```
select category, count(*) CategoryCount from table
group by category
```

Comment: What I have is a view in SQLServer which i am querying that has fields such as mobile, mother, date of birth, ect.
What i need to do it output different numbers to my display based on that persons data, 
I.e
#1 how many people have a mobile number,  
#2 how many people have children (requires some logic)

Some queries are easy, some are complex 
Is it better to run a query against the database for each one.
I.e select count (id) from table where mobile is not null

Or is it better to get a single table to the app from the DB and deal with all the heavy lifting at the app level?